# Rails: How do I pass a global variable from routes to controllers and helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails app that handles two domains. The app is set up like described in [this blogpost](http://www.nicolasgarnil.me/blog/2013/handling-multiple-domains-routes-in-ruby-on-rails/). Based on the base url that is visited, `routes.rb` determines which controller and which action should be triggered.

The two domains share a lot of files, e.g. `layouts/application.html.haml`, `layouts/footer.html.haml`, etc. But in `layouts/application.html.haml` I need to reference different navigation files. Usually I would simply write:

```
= render "layouts/navigation"
```

But with multiple domains I wish to write something like:

```
= render "layouts/#{domain_constraint}/navigation"
```

... `domain_constraint` here depending on the domain constraint that was matched in routes.

So how do I pass on this constraint from the routes, so I later on could access this constraint in a `helpers/application_helper.rb` method and a `controllers/application_controller.rb` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the blog post you referenced... it looks like `request.domain` should be available to you within your controllers and views. Meaning you should be able to key off of the value of the `request.domain` request header for rendering a layout.

```
= render "layouts/#{request.domain}/navigation"
```

Then, I would suggest to make your helper methods in ApplicationController and mark them as a [helper_method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method) as well.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :my_method

  def my_method
    # ... do whatever and access `request.domain` again if you want
  end
end
```

Methods marked as a helper method in this way will be available to controllers and views, alike.

Comment: Not required. Only if you want views to be able to access the method as well.